# How to suppress output of LibSVM in C++ [library mode]

Tags: c++, svm, libsvm

When LibSVM is executed from command line, i can give -q as a parameter and all will be ok. But, when i use it as a library, there is no -q parameter to set programmatically. How can i suppress the output then? There exist solutions in Java and python, but not in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same trick that they do in ***svm_train.c***.

- First define a function that does nothing:

  ```
  void print_null(const char *s) {}
  ```
- Then call the function that sets the printing:

  ```
  svm_set_print_string_function(&print_null);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?%20http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm%20zip) is distributed as source-code also. You can remove all not needed fprintf's or set the output function pointer info to 0

```
static int (*info)(const char *fmt,...) = 0;//&printf;
```

and build it again:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win lib
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svm_set_print_string_function([](auto c) {});
```